# Biblatex - prohibit line break between first and last name of author

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I am using a `biblatex-gost` package. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{halanay,
    langid = {english},
    title = {Differential Equations Stability, Oscillations, Time Lag},
    author = {A. Halanay},
    location = {New York--London},
    publisher = {Acad. Press},
    year = {1968},
    pagetotal = {568},
}
\end{filecontents}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-numeric,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\cite{halanay}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It produces

[image]

As you can see, there is a line break in the references between the author's first name and his last name. How do I prohibit this, so that `A. Halanay` is in the same line?

Note: `A.~Halanay` is not good since Biblatex thinks it's a single word and writes `A. Halanay` at the beginning of the line as well. But the GOST style requires `Halanay A.` at first, then `A. Halanay`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space between the given name and family name is controlled by `\bibnamedelimd`, which by default is `\addlowpenspace`, i.e. a space with a low penalty on line breaks.

You can use

```
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedelimd}{\addnbspace}
```

to avoid line breaks unconditionally.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{halanay,
    langid = {english},
    title = {Differential Equations Stability, Oscillations, Time Lag},
    author = {A. Halanay},
    location = {New York--London},
    publisher = {Acad. Press},
    year = {1968},
    pagetotal = {568},
}
\end{filecontents}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxbibnames=999, style=gost-numeric, language=auto, autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\bibnamedelimd}{\addnbspace}

\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\cite{halanay}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: No line break between "A." and "Halanay".]

Comment: Simple and elegant, as usual. Thank you @moewe!